# Dockerfile RUN mkdir not creating the file

Tags: docker, jenkins

At first I was having problems with

```
File or directory does not exist
```

So I looked on here and found the solution to add `-p`, therefore, my RUN mkdir is now:

```
RUN mkdir -p /home/myname/Docker/Jenkins
```

Although this gives me no errors, and works when I run docker build and docker run, the actual directory (Jenkins) does not get created in /home/myname/Docker, or anywhere in fact.

What is weird is that when I change to:

```
RUN mkdir /var/log/jenkins
```

and then `docker build & run`, there IS `jenkins` file inside of `/var/log`

So why wont it create in /home/myname/Docker when I request it does? Why does no Jenkins get created, there are no errors, so what is the problem? And whats the fix?

Thanks

EDIT: 
LinPy asked for my steps:

1. `vi Dockerfile`
2. Within the Dockefile there is:

```
    FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts
    LABEL maintainer="myemail"
    USER root
    RUN mkdir -p /home/karam/Docker/Jenkins
    RUN chown -R  jenkins:jenkins /home/karam/Docker/Jenkins
    USER jenkins
```

3. I then run `sudo docker build -t myjenkins .`
4. `sudo docker run -p 8080:8080 --name=jenkins-main -d myjenkins`

The container is now up and running, checking with `sudo docker ps`

But when I `ls` inside of file Docker, only the Dockerfile is there, no new directory called Jenkins.

Comment: add your steps to make it reproducable for us

Comment: forget about the Jenkins for a while and just verify the folder exist or not, `docker run --rm --name test -it  myjenkins bash -c "ls -l /home/karam/Docker/"`. this will give you an idea about internal folders and files. second thing are you running the command in the right container? are you mounting any files? and how you run `ls` inside docker? seems like you run `ls` in host that is why you see Dockerfile.

Comment: The user in the container isn't karam, so why even make that home folder?